# Is it possible to replace default from: with an email from database in Rails Action Mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I am trying to pass on an email from a user to the default from: field so that it looks like it's coming directly from them. Here is what I have right now. Is there any way of bringing in a dynamic variable into the default from field?

```
class IntroMailer < ActionMailer::Base
      default from: "Me@gmail.com"

      def intro_email(intro)
        @intro = intro
        mail(to: @intro.person1_email, subject: 'Testing Intro Email')
      end
    end
```

Comment: I searched for this answer and couldn't find it, can you point me in the right direction @mikej

Comment: It's not a duplicate. The author, I believe, is trying to use something like a lambda-expression as a default value, much like it's done in scopes. It looks like it's not implemented in Rails, yet this can be worked around. This will require some hackery, since there's no way we can tell the user behind this call...

Comment: Sorry Gary - have reread your question in more detail and can see it's different - have reopened it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override this in the Mailer action's `mail` method:

```
class IntroMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "Me@gmail.com"

  def intro_email(intro, current_user)
    mail(to: intro.person1_email, subject: 'Testing Intro Email', from: current_user.email)
  end
end
```

but a *WARNING*. Email clients, like Google, are pretty smart at detecting spam. If they see that a specific SMTP server is sending out emails with lots of different 'from' attributes, your spam rating will go up and your emails will be filtered out by spam filters. To get around this, choose one or two default `from` emails (e.g. support@mywebsite.com & jobs@mywebsite.com) that fit the email's type, and then add a dynamic `reply_to` attribute instead.

```
class IntroMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "ourteam@oursite.com"

  def intro_email(intro, current_user)
    mail(to: intro.person1_email, subject: 'Testing Intro Email', reply_to: full_from(current_user))
  end

  private

  def full_from(user)
    address = Mail::Address.new user.email
    address.display_name = user.full_name
    address.format
  end
end
```

Comment: Good catch about `reply_to`. Emails in web apps are hard to handle correctly, it's hard to find up-to-date info, that's unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

Actually not, it doesn't work at all in Rails 5.XX